# Will I break the eight precepts if I listen to nature sounds considered as music?

Tags: eight-precepts

During uposatha days, I'm getting a little confused with the interpretation of the seventh precept of eight precepts.

Is it possible for me to listen to nature sounds without any musical instruments' sounds? Even if they’re considered as 'music'?

Also, is there any text (from aṭṭhakathā or ṭīkā) explaining this precept? It would be great and very helpful.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

What is prohibited is the sounds (music) disturb your meditation and increase your attachment aversion and ignorance. You are allowed to substitute unwholesome sounds with wholesome sounds. 
For instance, you can listen to Pirith chanting or watch Dhamma video.

Answer (score 0):

Householder Alfa Renaldo Aluska, interested,

one is precept, one is kamma. Better always consider kamma while keeping precept anyway. Of course if one would delight on birds tweets... animals in the forest... such is not different to listen to music as it would be not different to delight in watching animals acts from attending shows. What ever entertains the mind in akusala way should be avoided to rejoice on it.

Some advices are found here, on how to grow into observing: [How to come to be able to observe precepts?](http://sangham.net/index.php/topic,8183.msg12964.html#msg12964)

*(Note that this gift of Dhamma is not dedicated for trade, exchange, stacks or entertainment but as a means to make merits toward release from this wheel)*